# Karate Response xml is not parsing and says not XML

Tags: xml, parsing, header, response, karate

I have a feature that returns response in xml format with

**Response xml:**

**Content-Type: application/xop+xml
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>
..
..
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

when I try to read karate.xmlPath(response) karate throws error not XML or cannot convert

how shall i ignore the extra lines received in the response with Content-Type which is blocking karate to read as valid xml

Comment: The `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary` requires extra processing since it's XML in binary encoding hence the `application/xop+xml`. I guess karate.xmlPath() expects plain string.

Comment: i manually removed those extra unwanted string and converted to xml and passed to the karate.xmlPath and it recognized now. thanks for your input!!

Comment: Could you add the karate specific code to the question please? Seems it could be useful for others in the future. Also, beware of those headers as they might not be "unwanted" but required to proper parse some responses. You can also add the karate code as an answer to your own question.

Comment: sure!!. Response xml that i receive had extra strings and karate complained its not a valid xml to parse it.  so I had to manually substring few characters and convert back the string to xml and parse it. i will post the response below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response xml:

```
content-type: '---'
content-transfer: '----'
<soap:Envelope>----</soap:Envelope>
```

Karate couldnt parse as it had characters and doesnt seem to be valid xml. Removed the unwanted characters using substring and converting back to xml fixed the issue

```
Given path '/endpoint'
And request requestpayload
And method post
Then status 200
* xml removeUnwantedString = response.substring(100)
* def parseResponse = karate.xmlPath(removeUnwantedString, 'Envelope/Body/column')
```

it got fixed and i was able to process it